# how to have a batch file answer questions automatically for an exe file?

Tags: batch-file

Alright so excuse my lack of knowledge, just actually started learning about coding and am trying something out with a few programs.

I have an `.exe` and a `.bat` file that I want to string together so that I have one `.bat` file that I run. I would rather not edit the other bat files. The problem is the `.exe` file l poses two questions and creates a `file.mesh`. Now the first question's answer is always `0` so I'm wondering if there's a way to enter the `0` outside of the `exe` file, and the second is the name of a file which I want to keep as user input.

In addition to that, I want to take the name that I just put in in the second question to automatically run through a second batch file which creates another file...

So essentially what I want is to have the .bat open and ask for a name of a file, then run both the exe and the other `.bat`. can anyone give me some direction as to where I should start researching or could help me write?

Comment: Is your EXE a _cli_ program? If not, look at AutoIt.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the EXE file is written, this may or may not work.  Try it and see.

```
 >file.txt echo 0
>>file.txt echo filename.bin
exefile.exe <file.txt
```

or

```
 >file.txt echo 0
>>file.txt echo filename.bin
type file.txt|exefile.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply a line in HelloWorld.bat should read:

```
     Echo 0 ¦ foobar.exe
```